# Как залить проект без изменений с ветки branch на master?

Tags: git

Не подумав, залил исходный код проекта на вторую ветку (branch). Начал делать изменения, коммитить, пушить на гитхаб. Мне необходимо исходный код проекта залит на ветку мастер. Как мне это сделать? Подскажите пожалуйста, я пока не разбираюсь в git.

Comment: Самое время разобраться. git merge

Answer (score 0):

практически точно так же, как вы «залили в branch», только «в master».

```
$ git push origin откуда:куда
```

- `откуда` — имя указателя в локальном хранилище («ветка» в программе *git* — это указатель на коммит).
- `куда` — имя указателя в хранилище, которое у вас подключено под именем `origin`

---

т.е., для приведённых вами имён:

```
$ git push origin branch:master
```